# IEnumerable<T> returning function implemented using 'yield return' versus creating a collection

Tags: c#

I am debating which of the following is an efficient way to implement the function `CreatePlayerData`

```
Method1: yield return
private static IEnumerable<IPlayerData> CreatePlayerData(int gameId, PlayerProfiles profiles)
{
    foreach (var data in profiles.data)
    {
        yield return new PlayerData
        {
            GameId = gameId,
            GameName = data.GameName,
            ProfileId = data.ProfileId
        };
    }
}

Method2: Creating a collection
private static IEnumerable<IPlayerData> CreatePlayerData(int gameId, PlayerProfiles profiles)
{
    var collection = new List<IPlayerData>();
    foreach (var data in profiles.data)
    {
        collection.Add(new PlayerData
        {
            GameId = gameId,
            GameName = data.GameName,
            ProfileId = data.ProfileId
        });
    }
    return collection;
}
```

There is a log function that uses function `CreatePlayerData` as an argument:
The signature of the log function is:

```
void LogPlayerData(IEnumerable<IPlayerData> players);
```

If I use `Method1` to implement `CreatePlayerData` function, I call the log function as:

```
LogPlayerData(CreatePlayerData().ToArray());
```

Or if I use `Method2` to implement `CreatePlayerData` function, I call the log function as:

```
LogPlayerData(CreatePlayerData());
```

Not sure which among `Method1` or `Method2` is the best way to implement the function `CreatePlayerData`. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Why do you need `ToArray` for the first and not the second? I think you need to show us how `LogPlayerData` is defined.

Comment: Note that `ToList()` is faster than `ToArray()` (except in cases where Linq knows the length of the collection) because `ToArray()` copies the list twice: first to build an internal `List<T>` and then a second time to trim it to an exactly-sized array (as `List<T>` can have spare capacity, an array cannot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the size of the collection, and the nature of the object and whether the surrounding code is able to take advantage of the benefits provided by `yield return`, and *many* other things related to *your* specific environment that are impossible for us to know.

Generally, if you have 10 million items, you're likely to be **whole lot better off** using `yield return`, because it helps write code that doesn't require every item be resident in memory at the same time.

If you have 4 items, you might do better with a collection, because there is some overhead creating and maintaining the state machine used by .Net behind the scenes... but at this point, you're gonna have a hard time measuring the difference.

Specifically, though, I want to mention the `.ToArray()` call in one of the samples. If you're calling `.ToArray()`, you **will** lose most of the benefits of `yield return`. Given the function is defined to accept an `IEnumerable<IPlayerData>`, you don't need the array conversion, and can shorten the code to just this:

```
LogPlayerData(CreatePlayerData());
```

Now we have less code, and we only need to keep **one** `PlayerData` object in memory at a time. Of course, we could still pass an array to this method if we really wanted (`IEnumerable<T>` is great like that); but don't call `ToArray()` or `ToList()` until you absolutely have to, which is often much later than you think.